# Using templates and strings?

Tags: c++, string, templates, stl

I have a handy function which splits a string into parts. The implementation is not important for my question.

```
inline std::vector<std::string> & split(const std::string & strInput, const std::string & strPattern, std::vector<std::string> & vec_strPart)
    {...}
```

I want to make a templated version of this function in order to support wstrings and other kinds of strings. However, if I do this

```
template <class StringType>
inline std::vector<StringType> & tsplit(const StringType & strInput, const StringType & strPattern, std::vector<StringType> & vec_strPart)
    {...}
```

then it does not work as expected

```
const std::string str("bla bla blaaaa");
const std::string strPattern(" ");
std::vector<std::string> vec_strPart;

split(str, strPattern, vec_strPart); // works
tsplit(str, strPattern, vec_strPart); // works
split(str, " ", vec_strPart); // works
tsplit(str, " ", vec_strPart); // does not work, StringType is ambiguous
tsplit(str, std::string(" "), vec_strPart); // works but changes client's code
```

My question is why using string constants does not work with the templated version while it works with the untemplated one. My assumption is that in the untemplated case, there is an implicit conversion from `char[]` to `std::string` while for templates, the matching occurs before implicit conversion.

How can I remedy the "ambiguity problem"? Can I maybe make a specialized version of `tsplit` which does the conversion to `std::string` and calls `tsplit`?

Comment: Maybe you could check the type of the variable in the split method (if modifying the client code is not allowed). Take a look at: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` and `const char*` are different type, so in

```
tsplit(str, " ", vec_strPart);
```

It is ambiguous if you want that `StringType` is `std::string` or `const char*`.

One way to fix that is to have template for each argument:

```
template <typename String, typename InputString, typename PatternString>
std::vector<String>& tsplit(const InputString & input,
                            const PatternString& pattern,
                            std::vector<String>& res);
```

An other way is to deduce only for one parameter, and make some arguments non deducible:

```
// Helper
template <typename T> struct non_deducible { using type = t; };
template <typename T> using non_deducible_t = typename non_deducible<T>::type;

template <typename String>
std::vector<String>& tsplit(const non_deducible_t<String>& input,
                            const non_deducible_t<String>& pattern,
                            std::vector<String>& res);
```

Comment: Is this C++03 or C++11?

Comment: Can be done in c++03, replace the `using type = t` by `typedef  t type;`, and remove definition of `non_deducible_t` and replace `non_deducible_t<String>` by `typename non_deducible<String>::type`.

Comment: Nice trick with non-deducible. Also +1 for actually answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your function like this

```
template <class StringType, class TextTypeA, class TextTypeB>
inline std::vector<StringType> & tsplit(TextTypeA strInput, TextTypeB strPattern, std::vector<StringType> & vec_strPart)
{
 ...   
}
```

Then your example compiles. The automatic conversion is then deferred to your implementation.

And so implementation matters ;-)

Comment: Do I then need to convert explicitly at the beginning of the implementation? Like this `const StringType strInputInternal(strInput); const StringType strPatternInternal(strPattern);` Another question: Do you have a special reason using call-by-value instead of call-by-ref?

Comment: Explicit conversion could be a simple solution, but other options may be available. Conversion could kick in automatically down the line. For example if you use a find_if explicityly use StringType to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Regarding call by value a const ref is probably better, you are right. But has to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <
    typename StringType,
    typename PatternStringType,
    typename ResultsStringType>

inline std::vector<ResultsStringType>& tsplit(
    const StringType& strInput,
    const PatternStringType& strPattern,
    std::vector<ResultsStringType>& vec_strPart)
{
    return vec_strPart; // your implementation
}
```

Out of topic: why return value if you give the third parameter and do you really need template parameter for resulting strings type? Maybe it'd be better to have one of the following:

```
template <typename StringType, typename PatternStringType>
inline std::vector<StringType> tsplit(const StringType& strInput, const PatternStringType& strPattern)
{
    return std::vector<StringType>(); // your implementation
}
```

or

```
template <typename StringType, typename PatternStringType>
inline void tsplit(const StringType& strInput, const PatternStringType& strPattern, std::vector<StringType>& resultingStrs)
{
    // your implementation
}
```